# Trying to mount a partition at installation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, mount

So I'm trying to mount a partition that i used as storage when i was using windows, and I'm not sure what option to choose on the "Use as" tab, some of the options are enabling "format the partition" section even though I am unchecking it

[image]

I still have data on /sda3 and i want to keep them.My intention is to install ubuntu on sda5 and use sda3 as storage disk.

Answer (score 2):

Don't select the NTFS partition at installation stage. Leave it alone.

After Ubuntu is installed, you'll be able to use that partition and/or mount it permanently somewhere.

**Note:** Having an NTFS partition on a system that doesn't have Windows installed is a bad idea. You won't be able to repair it properly if there is a problem.

I recommend to backup the data and create a Linux partition. You can do it later as well.

Comment: Alright so I'm selecting "do not use the partition" correct ?

Comment: This is correct.